# How to remove unique_ptr by pointer from a container?

Tags: c++11, unique-ptr

Creating an object and giving ownership to a container using a unique_ptr is no problem. How would one remove an element by raw pointer?

```
std::set<std::unique_ptr<MyClass>> mySet;

MyClass *myClass = new MyClass();
mySet.insert(std::unique_ptr<MyClass>(myClass));

// remove myClass from mySet?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to find the iterator corresponding to the `myClass` element and then pass that iterator to `mySet.erase()`. The iterator may be found using the `std::find_if` algorithm with a custom `Predicate` functor that understands how to dereference `unique_ptr` and compare it to the raw pointer `myClass`.

You can not use the overloaded `size_t set::erase ( const key_type& x );` since the raw pointer (even if wrapped in a temporary `unique_ptr`) will not be found in `mySet`.

Comment: If the raw pointer is wrapped in a temporary `unique_ptr<>`, §20.7.1.4/2 guarantees that the `set::size_type set::erase(key_type const&);` overload **will** work. However, that is almost guaranteed to create object lifetime issues unless a custom deleter is used for the temporary, so the `std::find_if` approach is probably still better.

Comment: I am failing to find the relevant section in either the 1998 standard, the revised 2003 standard or the new C++0X draft. Could you please direct me to the name of the correct document to which you are referring?

Comment: I am referring to the C++0x FDIS (N3290), §20.7.1.4/2, page 549.

Comment: As a side note, one could achieve std::set's logarithmic search time by re-factoring the code to use a `std::map<MyClass*, std::unique_ptr<MyClass>>` instead. There would be a little more memory overhead, but if we're talking about big sets that have elements deleted frequently, it's worth it to circumvent's `find_if`'s linear search time. Also, don't forget about `unordered_set` and `unordered_map`. They do most of the same things but have constant search time.

Comment: find_if is a bad approach because it's O(n), defeating the purpose of using a set<>

Answer (score 3):

Not as pretty as I would've liked.  But the following does the job:

```
#include <memory>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

struct do_nothing
{
    void operator()(const void*) const {}
};

struct MyClass
{
    MyClass() {std::cout << "MyClass()\n";}
    MyClass(const MyClass&) {std::cout << "MyClass(const MyClass&)\n";}
    ~MyClass() {std::cout << "~MyClass()\n";}
};

int main()
{
    std::set<std::unique_ptr<MyClass>> mySet;

    MyClass *myClass = new MyClass();
    mySet.insert(std::unique_ptr<MyClass>(myClass));

    // remove myClass from mySet?
    std::set<std::unique_ptr<MyClass>>::iterator i =
        lower_bound(mySet.begin(), mySet.end(),
                    std::unique_ptr<MyClass, do_nothing>(myClass));
    if (i != mySet.end() && *i == std::unique_ptr<MyClass, do_nothing>(myClass))
        mySet.erase(i);
}
```

Comment: Hm, this is fairly ugly, but I suppose that matches the unusual requirement: If the pointer is unique, then how could you even have another copy of it to search by value? I'm suspicious mainly of the OP's motives.

Comment: I think i have a good solution based on your proposal. See my posted solution.

Answer (score 1):

It seems i am able to retrieve an iterator using a custom Predicate with lower_bound. Since std::set is an ordered container, lower_bound should perform logarithmically.

```
std::set<std::unique_ptr<MyClass>>::iterator i =
    std::lower_bound(mySet.begin(), mySet.end(), myClass, MyPredicate<MyClass>());

template<class Type>
struct MyPredicate
{
    bool operator()(const std::unique_ptr<Type>& left, const Type* right) const
    {
        return left.get() < right;
    }
}
```

Comment: lower_bound is not logarithmic in this case because the iterator returned by set<>.begin()/set<>.end() is not a RandomAccessIterator.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound

Answer (score 0):

Still not the best solution but for the moment i go with:

```
PointerMap<MyFoo>::Type myFoos;

MyFoo * myFoo = new MyFoo();
myFoos.insert(PointerMap<MyFoo>::Item(myFoo));
```

The header is:

```
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
struct PointerMap
{
    typedef std::map<T *, std::unique_ptr<T>> Type;

    struct Item : std::pair<T *, std::unique_ptr<T>>
    {
        Item(T * pointer)
            : std::pair<T *, std::unique_ptr<T>>(pointer, std::unique_ptr<T>(pointer))
        {
        }
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You might like the answer over here: [Efficiently erase a unique_ptr from an unordered_set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60220220/efficiently-erase-a-unique-ptr-from-an-unordered-set/60220391#60220391)

That's for C++14, but I think applies to C++11 as well.

It is not pretty, but does the efficient thing — no scanning the container, but using proper hash-based lookup.